# Uniformly Regulating Program Execution Rate [Windows C++]

Tags: c++, windows, sleep

First off, I found a lot of information on this topic, but no solutions that solved the issue unfortunately.

I'm simply trying to regulate my C++ program to run at 60 iterations per second. I've tried everything from GetClockTicks() to GetLocalTime() to help in the regulation but every single time I run the program on my Windows Server 2008 machine, it runs slower than on my local machine and I have no clue why!

I understand that "clock" based function calls return CPU time spend on the execution so I went to GetLocalTime and then tried to differentiate between the start time and the stop time then call Sleep((FPS / 1000) - millisecondExecutionTime)

My local machine is quite faster than the servers CPU so obviously the thought was that it was going off of CPU ticks, but that doesn't explain why the GetLocalTime doesn't work. I've been basing this method off of http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson14/index.php changing the get_ticks() with all of the time returning functions I could find on the web.

For example take this code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int tFps = 60;
    int counter = 0;

    SYSTEMTIME gStart, gEnd, start_time, end_time;

    GetLocalTime( &gStart );

    bool done = false;
    while(!done) {
        GetLocalTime( &start_time );

        Sleep(10);
        counter++;

        GetLocalTime( &end_time );

        int startTimeMilli = (start_time.wSecond * 1000 + start_time.wMilliseconds);
        int endTimeMilli = (end_time.wSecond * 1000 + end_time.wMilliseconds);

        int time_to_sleep = (1000 / tFps) - (endTimeMilli - startTimeMilli);


        if (counter > 240)
            done = true;

        if (time_to_sleep > 0)
            Sleep(time_to_sleep);
    }

    GetLocalTime( &gEnd );

    cout << "Total Time: " << (gEnd.wSecond*1000 + gEnd.wMilliseconds) - (gStart.wSecond*1000 + gStart.wMilliseconds) << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

For this code snippet, run on my computer (3.06 GHz) I get a total time (ms) of 3856 whereas on my server (2.53 GHz) I get 6256. So it potentially could be the speed of the processor though the ratio of 2.53/3.06 is only .826797386 versus 3856/6271 is .614893956.

I can't tell if the Sleep function is doing something drastically different than expected though I don't see why it would, or if it is my method for getting the time (even though it should be in world time (ms) not clock cycle time. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: just to share, when i was working on a game engine (dead project now) I wrote this: [Game Time Library](https://github.com/killertypo/SpriteWorks2D/blob/master/SpriteWorks2D/SWGameClock.cpp) and you can see the [impl](https://github.com/killertypo/seed/blob/master/seed/main/WinMain.cpp).  It always worked perfectly for me when ensuring i was running at an exact frame rate, even accounted for skip frames in case rendering slowed down.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon Thanks for the share, looks a little daunting but I'll definitely take a look at it.

Comment: If you want accurate timed execution of code; don't use Sleep, use a timer.

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, Sleep's default resolution is the computer's quota length - usually either 10ms or 15ms, depending on the Windows edition. To get a resolution of, say, 1ms, you have to issue a timeBeginPeriod(1), which reprograms the timer hardware to fire (roughly) once every millisecond.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Why does it take in ms if it's not that accurate? Any suggestions on a replacement?

Comment: Only the API designers can answer that, obviously, but it would be somewhat awkward if the meaning of the argument changed depending on the version and edition of O/S the code was running on.

Comment: Sleep isn't for timing; hence it's inherent lack of accurate granularity.

Answer (score 1):

In your main loop you can

```
int main() 
{
    // Timers
    LONGLONG curTime = NULL;
    LONGLONG nextTime = NULL;

    Timers::GameClock::GetInstance()->GetTime(&nextTime);
    while (true) {    
        Timers::GameClock::GetInstance()->GetTime(&curTime);
        if ( curTime > nextTime  && loops <= MAX_FRAMESKIP ) { 
            nextTime += Timers::GameClock::GetInstance()->timeCount;

            // Business logic goes here and occurr based on the specified framerate
        }
    }
}
```

using this time library

```
include "stdafx.h"

LONGLONG cacheTime;

Timers::SWGameClock* Timers::SWGameClock::pInstance = NULL;

Timers::SWGameClock* Timers::SWGameClock::GetInstance ( ) { 
    if (pInstance == NULL) { 
        pInstance = new SWGameClock();
    }
    return pInstance;
}


Timers::SWGameClock::SWGameClock(void) {
    this->Initialize ( );
}

void Timers::SWGameClock::GetTime ( LONGLONG * t ) { 
    // Use timeGetTime() if queryperformancecounter is not supported 
    if (!QueryPerformanceCounter( (LARGE_INTEGER *) t)) { 
        *t = timeGetTime();
    }

    cacheTime = *t;
}

LONGLONG Timers::SWGameClock::GetTimeElapsed ( void ) { 
    LONGLONG t; 

    // Use timeGetTime() if queryperformancecounter is not supported
    if (!QueryPerformanceCounter( (LARGE_INTEGER *) &t )) { 
        t = timeGetTime();
    }

    return (t - cacheTime);
}

void Timers::SWGameClock::Initialize ( void ) { 
    if ( !QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER *) &this->frequency) ) { 
        this->frequency = 1000; // 1000ms to one second 
    }
    this->timeCount = DWORD(this->frequency / TICKS_PER_SECOND);
}

Timers::SWGameClock::~SWGameClock(void)
{
}
```

with a header file that contains the following:

```
// Required for rendering stuff on time
#pragma once
#define TICKS_PER_SECOND 60
#define MAX_FRAMESKIP 5

namespace Timers { 
    class SWGameClock
    {
    public:
        static SWGameClock* GetInstance();
        void Initialize ( void );
        DWORD timeCount;

        void GetTime ( LONGLONG* t );
        LONGLONG GetTimeElapsed ( void );
        LONGLONG frequency; 

        ~SWGameClock(void);
    protected:
        SWGameClock(void);

    private:
        static SWGameClock* pInstance;
    }; // SWGameClock
} // Timers
```

This will ensure that your code runs at 60FPS (or whatever you put in) though you can probably dump the MAX_FRAMESKIP as that's not truly implemented in this example!

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `WinMain` function and use the `SetTimer` function and a regular message loop (you can also take advantage of the filter mechanism of `GetMessage( ... )` ) in which you test for the `WM_TIMER` message with the requested time and when your counter reaches the limit do a `PostQuitMessage(0)` to terminate the message loop.

Comment: Windows timer messages are pretty bad for the accuracy needed.  They tend to be delayed by other messages in the queue, and, even when there are no other messages, the accuracy depends on a fairly coarse clock.

Answer (score 0):

For a duty cycle that fast, you can use a high accuracy timer (like QueryPerformanceTimer) and a busy-wait loop.

If you had a much lower duty cycle, but still wanted precision, then you could Sleep for part of the time and then eat up the leftover time with a busy-wait loop.

Another option is to use something like DirectX to sync yourself to the VSync interrupt (which is almost always 60 Hz).  This can make a lot of sense if you're coding a game or a/v presentation.

Windows is not a real-time OS, so there will never be a perfect way to do something like this, as there's no guarantee your thread will be scheduled to run exactly when you need it to.

Note that in the [remarks for Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the actual amount of time will be at least one "tick" and possible one whole "tick" longer than the delay you requested before the thread is scheduled to run again (and then we have to assume the thread is scheduled).  The "tick" can vary a lot depending on hardware and the version of Windows.  It is commonly in the 10-15 ms range, and I've seen it as bad as 19 ms.  For 60 Hz, you need 16.666 ms per iteration, so this is obviously not nearly precise enough to give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What about rendering (iterating) based on the time elapsed between rendering of each frame? Consider creating a `void render(double timePassed)` function and render depending on the `timePassed` parameter instead of putting program to sleep.

Imagine, for example, you want to render a ball falling or bouncing. You would know it's speed, acceleration and all other physics that you need. Calculate the position of the ball based on `timePassed` and all other physics parameters (speed, acceleration, etc.).

Or if you prefer, you could just skip the `render()` function execution if time passed is a value to small, instead of puttin program to sleep.

Comment: As someone already mentioned, `sleep()` depends on how busy a machine is, so a busy server might schedule your application to processor after the moment you need, causing the application to appear slower.